# Is there a way to make superscripts larger?

Tags: fonts, xy-pic, superscripts

Is there a way to make superscripts larger? Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}    

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A \\ B\ar@{}[u]^{\circlearrowleft} }
\end{document}
```

and I would like the `\circlearrowleft` to be larger. The following, for example, doesn't work:

```
\xymatrix{A \\ B\ar@{}[u]^{
    \begin{Huge}
      \circlearrowleft
    \end{Huge}
} }
```

Comment: An easy scaling technique for resizing symbols is via [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx): `\usepackage{graphicx}...\scalebox{2}{$\circlearrowleft$}` will double the size of `\circlearrowleft`.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scaling is possible on a "factor" basis via [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/)'s `\scalebox{<num>}{<stuff>}` or "length/dimension" basis via `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<stuff>}`. Here is a minimal example showing the former:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
\xymatrix{A \\ B\ar@{}[u]^{\circlearrowleft} }
\end{minipage} \quad
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
\xymatrix{A \\ B\ar@{}[u]^{\scalebox{2}{$\circlearrowleft$}} }
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Since both `\scalebox` and `\resizebox` resets the contents to text mode, you have to switch back to math mode using `$...$`.

Answer (score 8):

A quick way is using `\Huge` etc. inside `\mbox`:

```
...^{\mbox{\Huge$\circlearrowleft$}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
  {} & M = H^1_{\text{cris}}(J_C, Z_p) \ar[dr]  & \\
  J_C\ar@{-->}[ru] \ar@{-->}[rd] & &  H^1_{\text{dR}}(J_C, F_p) \\
  & \{J_C[p^n]\}_n \ar@{-->}[uu] & V^{-1}\colon df \mapsto
  \frac{\text{``}d(f^p)\text{"}}{p}\ar@{}[u]^{\mbox{\Huge$\circlearrowleft$}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: xypic diagram]